# Cursor can't move to first

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Hi I'm working on a project, it contains a database.
After creating the database and inserting data into database I want to send data into another intent. There are image buttons on my app when user touch one of those, another intent opens up and shows info about that imageButton.

So I send the ID of the touched `imageButton` so I know what is the source button. As the code below doesn't perform the "if" body [`if(cursor.moveToFirst()`]. What is the problem with cursor? Why it cant move to first?

This is the intent that should show the information.

`IDVALUE` is the id of `imageButtons`. I checked it, works fine.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);

    Bundle IDbundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    IDVALUE = IDbundle.getInt("cnt0");
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Info_textView1);

    cursor = MainActivity.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM movieInfo WHERE movie_id = '+IDVALUE+'",null);
    if(cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            tv1.setText(cursor.getString(2));
        }
    }
```

There are two records on my database (codes are in `MainActivity`), one 
contains `id` and the other contains `information`

```
private void InitialDatabase() {

    try {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "infoFile");

        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdir();
        }

        File file = new File(root, "info");

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(file, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" +
                " movieInfo(movie_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,movie_info TEXT)");
                //now i have a data base with two record
        db.execSQL("INSERT  INTO movieInfo (movie_info) VALUES('1')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT  INTO movieInfo (movie_info) VALUES('2')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT  INTO movieInfo (movie_info) VALUES('3')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT  INTO movieInfo (movie_info) VALUES('4')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT  INTO movieInfo (movie_info) VALUES('5')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT  INTO movieInfo (movie_info) VALUES('6')");



    } catch (IOException io) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "error on initialing dataBase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

and this is my database codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> "SELECT * FROM movieInfo WHERE movie_id = '+IDVALUE+'"
> ```

You're matching for literal `+IDVALUE+`, not the data contained in a Java variable named `IDVALUE`. Change to:

```
"SELECT * FROM movieInfo WHERE movie_id = '" + IDVALUE + "'"
```

Note that `MainActivity.db.rawQuery()` looks suspicious - if this code is not in MainActivity, you cannot rely that some other activity has initialised its fields. Open a new database reference instead in that activity.

Comment: thank u very much it works now, someone told me to put plus besides of IDVALUE but I didn't get it. now I know why is that for.thank you so much